# Flash cs5 code location confusion

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, class, flash-cs5, document-class

Whenever I place the following code on the first frame of my movie, it works fine:

```
var strGlobal:String = "Global"; 
function scopeTest() 
{ 
    trace(strGlobal); // Global 
} 
scopeTest(); 
trace(strGlobal); // Global
```

But when I remove it and place it in my document class, it errors out:
"Call to a possible undefined method scopeTest"
"Access to undefined property strGlobal"

I am new to actionscript 3 and was wondering what to change to make this simple example work from my main document class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same directory as your .fla file create a file named **ScopeTest.as** and define the following class:

```
package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    public class ScopeTest extends MovieClip  {
        var strGlobal:String = "Global"; 
        public function ScopeTest() {
            trace(strGlobal); // Global 
        }
    }
}
```

Then inside your .fla project (document class):

[image]

Then when you run it you should get "Global" traced out to confirm it works.

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a look at writing a document class.

Step 1: Declaring the package - package represents where relative to the .fla your document class is stored. If your document class is in the same directory as the .fla, you'll just need to write:

```
package
```

If it's in a folder, you'll need to add that after `package`. Let's say your document class was in a directory called `src`:

```
package src
```

Now that that's sorted, you should have something like this:

```
package
{
    //
}
```

The next thing you need to do is import the classes that you'll need to use in your document class. You'll want to extend `MovieClip` in your document class, so lets import that:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
}
```

That's all we'll need to cover your example, so now we move onto the third element required, the class declaration. In this case, it is made up of three parts:

1. The class namespace - can be either `internal` (if you only want your class to be accessible from classes in the same package) or `public` (accessible anywhere in the project).
2. Your class name.
3. What your class will extend - in this case, MovieClip.

All together, yours will look like this:

```
public class Document extends MovieClip
```

Now you'll have something like the below, which means you can start adding `properties` and `methods`:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Document extends MovieClip
    {
        //
    }
}
```

The first thing you'll want to do is create a `constructor` for your class. The constructor is called when an instance of this class is created, or in your case being a document class, immediately.

Constructors are defined by creating a method with the same name as its containing class. Constructors must also be `public` and return nothing. Here's your new code with an empty constructor:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Document extends MovieClip
    {
        // Constructor
        public function Document()
        {
            //
        }
    }
}
```

Next step is to create your properties that will belong to your class. In your example you used `strGlobal:String`, so let's add that. Properties generally belong immediately below the class declaration and above the constructor. Properties are made up of four parts:

1. Namespace - this determines the accessibility of your property. If you omit this, the default will be `internal`. For now, these are the basics:

   - `public` - Your property is accessible from anywhere that have reference to an instance of your class.
   - `private` - Your property is only accessible from within the class - this seems useless at first, but eventually you'll find yourself primarily using this.
   - `protected` - Your property is accessible in classes that extend your class.
   - `internal` - Your property is accessible from classes that are in the same package.
2. Your property name.
3. Your property type.
4. Your property value.

In your case, `strGlobal` will look something like this:

```
public var strGlobal:String = "Global";
```

Let's add that to your document class:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Document extends MovieClip
    {
        // Properties
        public var strGlobal:String = "Global";

        // Constructor
        public function Document()
        {
            //
        }
    }
}
```

Next up, you'll want to create your method `scopeTest()` as per your question. Methods are made up of 5 parts:

1. Namespace - methods use the same namespaces as properties (see above).
2. Method name.
3. Method arguments.
4. Return type.
5. Content.

`scopeTest()` doesn't have any arguments and doesn't return anything, so it's going to look like this:

```
public function scopeTest():void
{
    trace(strGlobal);
}
```

Methods generally belong anywhere below your constructor, so let's slot it in now:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Document extends MovieClip
    {
        // Properties
        public var strGlobal:String = "Global";

        // Constructor
        public function Document()
        {
            //
        }

        // Output the value of strGlobal
        public function scopeTest():void
        {
            trace(strGlobal);
        }
    }
}
```

Now that everything is ready, you'll be able to call `scopeTest()` from within your constructor. Because the constructor is called immediately, you should see `Global` printed in your output panel (assuming you've linked to it within the Flash IDE correctly).

Hope this helps.